# Differentiate between select values in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a dynamic dropdown list using product, make, and models. When creating the dropdown list selections, how do I differentiate between the select values if they have the same name. My current script returns the same value although a different product was selected. Also, how do I center the select id values and dropdown list values. Any help provided is appreciated.

```
    <select id="company" name="company" class="form-control linked- 
   dropdown" data-linked="make">
  <option value="">-- Select Product --</option>
  <option value="Product1">Product1</option>
  <option value="Product2">Product2</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  </div>
  <select id="make" name="make" class="form-control linked-
         dropdown" data-linked="model">
    <option value="">Choose Make</option>    
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
    <select id="model" name="model" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose Model</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   </div>
   </form>

   <script>
   var dataFirstSelect = {
   option: ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3']
    }
   var dataSecondSelect = {
   Product1: ['Model 1', 'Model 2', 'Model_3', 'Model_4'],
   Product2: ['Model 1', 'Model 2', 'Model_7', 'Model_8']
   }
   var dataThirdSelect = {
   'Model 1': ['Make1-1-1', 'Make1-1-2', 'Make1-1-3', 'Make1-1-4'],
   'Model 2': ['Make1-1-1', 'Make1-1-2', 'Make1-2-3', 'Make1-2-4'],
   'Model_3': ['Make1-3-1', 'Make1-3-2', 'Make1-3-3', 'Make1-3-4'],
    }

    $('#company').on('change', function() {
    var a = $(this).val();
     if (a !== '') {
    for (var i = 0; i < dataSecondSelect[a].length; i++) {
     $('#make').append($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", dataSecondSelect[a][i])
    .text(dataSecondSelect[a][i]));
       }
       }
       });
     $('#make').on('change', function() {
     var b = $(this).val();
     if (b !== '') {
     for (var i = 0; i < dataThirdSelect[b].length; i++) {
     $('#model').append($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", dataThirdSelect[b][i])
    .text(dataThirdSelect[b][i]));
    }
    }
    });

    function openDoc(url) {
    window.open         
    (url, "_blank", "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars= 
     yes, status = yes ");
     }
    $('#clickButton').on('click', function() {
    var data = new Object;
    $('select').each(function() {
    //console.log($(this));
     data[$(this)["0"].id] = $(this).val();
    });
    openDoc(data.model);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Because you know what was in the first select, you know what which one is in the second  so you also know how to set up the third.

Comment: My question is how to differentiate between the select values if they have the same name. Currently, the script returns the value from Product 1 & Product 2 b/c two of the values have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

your basic problem is that you are not clearing the previous options on select changes. Each time the user changes a selection, the number of options gets longer so you don't know what is what. The code below fixes this.  Note my changes in your event handlers.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
            <script>
                var dataFirstSelect = {
                    option: ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3']
                }
                var dataSecondSelect = {
                    Product1: ['Model 1', 'Model 2', 'Model_3'],
                    Product2: ['Model 1', 'Model 2', 'Model_7', 'Model_8']
                }
                var dataThirdSelect = {
                    'Model 1': ['Make1-1-1', 'Make1-1-2', 'Make1-1-3', 'Make1-1-4'],
                    'Model 2': ['Make1-1-1', 'Make1-1-2', 'Make1-2-3', 'Make1-2-4'],
                    'Model_3': ['Make1-3-1', 'Make1-3-2', 'Make1-3-3', 'Make1-3-4'],
                }

                $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('#company').on('change', function () {

                        $('#model').html("<option value=''>Waiting on Make</option>")
                        var a = $(this).val();

                        if (a !== '') {
                            $('#make').html("<option value=''>Select Make</option>");
                            for (var i = 0; i < dataSecondSelect[a].length; i++) {
                                $('#make').append($("<option></option>")
                               .attr("value", dataSecondSelect[a][i])
                               .text(dataSecondSelect[a][i]));
                            }
                        } else {
                            $('#make').html("<option value=''>Waiting on Comapny</option>");
                        }
                    });
                    $('#make').on('change', function() {
                        var b = $(this).val();
                        if (b !== '') {
                            $('#model').html("<option value=''>Select Model</option>")
                            for (var i = 0; i < dataThirdSelect[b].length; i++) {
                                $('#model').append($("<option></option>")
                               .attr("value", dataThirdSelect[b][i])
                               .text(dataThirdSelect[b][i]));
                            }
                        } else {
                            $('#model').html("<option value=''>Waiting on Make</option>")
                        }
                    });

                    $('#clickButton').on('click', function () {

                        var data = new Object;
                        $('select').each(function () {
                            //console.log($(this));
                            data[$(this)["0"].id] = $(this).val();
                        });
                        alert(data.model);
                    });
                });

                function openDoc(url) {
                    window.open         
                    (url, "_blank", "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes, status = yes ");
                }


            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
            <select id="company" name="company" class="form-control linked-
           dropdown" data-linked="make">
                <option value="">-- Select Product --</option>
                <option value="Product1">Product1</option>
                <option value="Product2">Product2</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div>
            <select id="make" name="make" class="form-control linked-
                 dropdown" data-linked="model">
                <option value="">Waiting on Company</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div>
            <select id="model" name="model" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Waiting on Make</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <button type="button" id="clickButton">button</button>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Work perfectly, thank you. Any thoughts on how to center the select id values and dropdown list values?

Comment: I actually uses a select box plugin called select2. It looks better and gives you the ability to fully customize your display. https://select2.org/

Comment: If, down the road, you are considering all makes and models and years, you will need an ajax / database solution. You will not be able to send that much info to a client browser